# Recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

I have an array list that could contain component or composite and each component or composite has a tax field that i would like to get the value.The purpose of this method is to get the total tax due by all the components and composites in the array list.A component can also contain a composite .The problem is when a component contains a composite ,My method does not get the value in the composite

```
ArrayList allprinceSubjects = new ArrayList();
public double calculateTaxDueByComponents(){
    double totaltaxdue=0;
    Iterator iterator = vassalsanddukes.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        RiruritaniaSubjects vassalandduke=(RiruritaniaSubjects) iterator.next();
        totaltaxdue+=vassalandduke.getTaxDue();
        vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();


    }
    return totaltaxdue;
}
```

Comment: Others have answered already, but what does `getTaxDue()` do? It seems like it would make more sense to move the logic from `calculateTaxDueByComponents` to `getTaxDue` and only have a single method. Or at least call `calculateTaxDueByComponents` from within `getTaxDue` so that you don't need to do both things explicitly every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure how your business logic are implemented, but I think the following line needs changing:

```
vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();
```

Change it to:

```
totaltaxdue += vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you when you call `calculateTaxDueByComponents()` recursively, you discard the result:

```
vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();
```

Change that to

```
totaltaxdue += vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();
```

Comment: +1 It makes no sense to call `vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();` **after** `totaltaxdue` has been increased.

Comment: THanks that solved my problem ,I would have to relearn recursion,Any tips on the best way to learn recursion

Comment: @Jackwelch: Your problem had nothing with recursion, but with proper arranging of statements.

Answer (score 1):

you're not assigning the value of `vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();` to anything - you should most likely be adding it to totaltaxdue, not so?

Answer (score 0):

store that return value of method in totaltaxdue like below.

`totaltaxdue += vassalandduke.calculateTaxDueByComponents();`

Comment: Not a good idea. That would increase its value on each call to the method.