# Recursive method not giving the correct value

Tags: java, recursive-query

I want to use a recursive method but am having trouble making it work correctly.

In this program for example, why when I display my `b`, the value is 0 and not 10?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
     int a = 0;

     int b = recursivMethod(a);
     System.out.println(b);
}

static int recursivMethod(int a)
{
    if(a != 10)
        recursivMethod(a+1);

    return a;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8849785/recursive-method

Answer (score 5):

The issue is, while you are *calling* the method recursively, you're not *returning* that value. That is, you call `recursivMethod` correctly, but then immediately return the initial value of `a`. Try this instead:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0;

    int b = recursivMethod(a);
    System.out.println(b);
}

static int recursivMethod(int a)
{
    if(a != 10)
        return recursivMethod(a+1); //here, you return the result of your recursive call

    return a; //instead of just immediately returning a, which should only be done only after a == 10
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Two points:

1. When your method calls itself recursively, it's ignoring the returned value:

   ```
   if(a != 10)
      recursivMethod(a+1); // <--- did you mean to do something with the result?
   ```
2. Since `recursivMethod()` doesn't change `a`, and returns `a` at the end, then calling `recursivMethod(0)` will return `0`. This is exactly what happens when you run your code.

Comment: but i called it with a+1 ! then it increment each call, no ?

Comment: @user1149157: No it doesn't. Each invocation gets its own copy of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are ignoring the return value of your recursive invocation:

```
static int recursivMethod(int a) {
    if(a != 10)
        return recursivMethod(a+1);
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
return recursiveMethod(a+1);
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

You did never assign a new value to the method local variable `a`.
Try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   int a = 0;

   int b = recursivMethod(a);
   System.out.println(b);
}

static int recursivMethod(int a)
{
  if(a != 10)
    a = recursivMethod(a+1);

  return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are discarding the result of your recursive call.

```
static int recursivMethod(int a)
{
    if(a != 10)
        return recursivMethod(a+1); // Note the return

    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static int recursivMethod(int a)
{
if(a != 10)
    return recursivMethod(a+1);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

missing return:

```
return recursivMethod(a+1);
```